DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing - Keep font and size same as rest of document
The template I have is in font Calibri (bold), Fontsize 11. I am inserting a paragraph with a run. My initial problem was, whereever I inserted a paragraph in the document, the font and fontsize would differ from that of the template. I want it to be the same as the rest of the document. After alot of struggle I manage to set the Font size and Font for a paragraph that has been inserted. The question now is how to adopt the initial font and fontsize that the template aleady has??
THis is the code I have to specific set the font and fontsize:
public override OpenXmlElement AddToDocumentAfter(WordprocessingDocument document, Paragraph basedOn,
  OpenXmlElement after)
{
    foreach (string line in _textLines)
    {
        Paragraph newP = CloneParagraphWithoutContent(basedOn);

        after.InsertAfterSelf(newP);
        Run run = newP.AppendChild(new Run());

        var runProp = new RunProperties();
        var runFont = new RunFonts { Ascii = "Calibri (Body)" };
        var size = new FontSize { Val = new StringValue("22") };

        runProp.Append(runFont);
        runProp.Append(size);

        run.AppendChild(new Text(line));
        run.PrependChild(runProp);

        if (_styleElements.Any())
            run.FindOrAddDescendant<RunProperties>(true).Append(_styleElements);
        after = newP;
    }

    return after;
}

